# Why is there a red dot on the right of my "Time" slider?

Tags: manipulate

Here is my code

```
Theta[t_, theta0_, thetad0_, l_, b_] :=
  With[{
    wd = Sqrt[-b^2 + 4 9.81/l]/2
    },
   Exp[-b/
       2 t] (theta0 Cos[wd t] + (thetad0 + b/2 theta0)/wd Sin[wd t])];
Thetad[t_, theta0_, thetad0_, l_, b_] := 
  With[{
    wd = Sqrt[b^2 + 4 9.81/l]/2,
    A = theta0,
    B = (thetad0 + b/2 theta0)/(Sqrt[-b^2 + 4 9.81/l]/2)
    },
   Exp[-b/2 t] ((B wd - A b/2) Cos[wd t] - (b/2 B + A wd) Sin[wd t])];
Manipulate[GraphicsGrid[{{
    Graphics[{Line[{{0, 
         0}, {l Sin[Theta[t, theta0, thetad0, l, b]], -l Cos[
           Theta[t, theta0, thetad0, l, b]]}}],
      Disk[{l Sin[Theta[t, theta0, thetad0, l, b]], -l Cos[
          Theta[t, theta0, thetad0, l, b]]}, 0.05],
      Line[{{-0.1, 0}, {-0.1, 0}}], {Gray, Dashed, 
       Line[{{0, 0}, {0, -1}}]}
      }, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1.1, 0.1}}],
    Plot[-l Cos[Theta[s, theta0, thetad0, l, b]], {s, 0, t}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 8 Pi}, {-1, 0}}]},
   {Rotate[
     Plot[-l Sin[Theta[s, theta0, thetad0, l, b]], {s, 0, t}, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 8 Pi}, {-1, 1}}], -Pi/2],
    ParametricPlot[{Theta[s, theta0, thetad0, l, b], 
      Thetad[s, theta0, thetad0, l, b]}, {s, 0, t}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-3, 3}}]}}],
 {{t, 0.1, "Time"}, 0.2, 8 Pi, 0.01},
 {{theta0, Pi/6, "Initial Displacement"}, -Pi/4, Pi/4, 0.01},
 {{thetad0, 0, "Initial Velocity"}, -1, 1, 0.05},
 {{l, 0.9, "Length"}, 0.5, 1},
 {{b, 0.1, "Damping Coefficient"}, {0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6}}]
```

*Here is a pic of this weird phenomenon*

[image]

Comment: Next time please try to construct a *minimal* example.

Comment: Was about the write the same comment... =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red mark means that the value of the variable associated with the slider is outside of the range of the slider. You set the value to 0.1 but you set the range to start at 0.2.